# How to set IP Filtering under IIS6

Tags: iis-6, scripting

we have a particular application under a virtual directory that is used for administatrive purposes.  In order to protect the application, we have IP filtering enabled where we specify a list of allowed IPs that can connect.

Manually setting this up the first time is fine, however the way our deployment tools work; they always uninstall and then reinstall any programs that require updating.  Which means I lose my settings each time and have to re-enter.

Since my list of IPs is easily 15-20, I woudl like to automate this via a script -- Powershell, VBScript, whatever.

I'm not sure there is an API or another way this can be set.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: IP filtering is done on the Operating System level and not on application server level. So put your IPs in the firewall where they belong to.

Comment: Why not just back up the metabase before the (incredibly strange) upgrade process, and restore it afterward?

Comment: @mailq I believe because it's an IP access list for a specific virtual directory, rather than the entire web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to at least minimize the effort you need to put into this: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Apr/28/Blocking-IIS-IP-Addresses-with-ASPNET